# Convert String to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to convert a string which is of the format August 1, 2011 to a NSDate.

I used the following code

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Aug 3, 2011";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, YYYY"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];  

[picker setDate:date animated:YES];
```

But the output is get is not the December 26, 2010 in the date picker.

Comment: "Aug 3, 2011" and "August 1, 2011" are not in the same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your comment on Bertrand Marron's answer, if you are sure you have the date formatter right, perhaps the problem is with your picker? Can you check the value of the date in the debugger and confirm that is correct? Is your picker a custom subclass or the standard date picker?

EDIT:

After reproducing this myself, I have the answer.

Replace

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, YYYY"];
```

with

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM d, yyyy"];
```

Upper case YYYY indicates "Week of year" in the ISO year-week calendar. See documentation for data formatting guide --> Date formatters for example.

Comment: It us a standard Date picker .. Yes i checked while debugging after the statement NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];  the date is set to december 26, 2010.. Could not resolve it till now..Awaiting for a proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should specify:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM d, YYYY"];
```

Have also a look at [this document](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns):

> Month - Use one [M] or two for the numerical month, three for the abbreviation, or four for the full name, or five for the narrow name.

(The "narrow name" is something like the initial of the month; you are looking for the abbreviation)

Answer (score 0):

try this it may use

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM d, YYYY"];

Answer (score 0):

Your date is not formatted like "August 1, 2011".

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Aug 3, 2011";
```

The correct format string would be `@"MMM d, YYYY"`

Although `@"MMMM d, YYYY"` would work for `@"August 1, 2011"`.

Comment: Sorry i made mistake while writing my question in the first place . I had given the String as "August 3, 2011" and the format as "MMMM d, YYYY" But the result i keep getting is December 26, 2011 in the picker

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];// autorelease    
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, YYYY hh:mma"];
```